# knockout,js: Iterating through a "strongly-typed" observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaquio/8bW3Y/) to illustrate my issue.

I'm trying to use "strongly-typed" objects throughout my application (SPA). The reason is that I was having issues with differences between objects coming from the server and those created at run-time. Although both have the same properties, there were some missing CRUD functions and, in some cases, enumerations for dropdowns. Now I find I can't use the foreach binding because my observableArray has no elements but on the code side it does. I've done something similar on another SPA but the difference is that on the other I didn't use ko.observable* on all properties. The other one worked fine. (EDIT: I removed the ko.observable on the properties and the behaviour continued).

The application has two viewmodels: AppViewModel and StrongViewModel. AppViewModel orchestrates the whole application while StrongViewModel is a subset of the application. When a user wants to run a process chosenProcessId is set and then it will load the data from the process into chosenProcessData. All the results of chosenProcessData are shown in a table.

Start the application:

```
var app = new AppViewModel();
app.initialize();
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

Load the first process:

```
self.initialize = function () {
self.goToProcess(self.processes()[0]);
};
```

User selects second process (strongly-typed) and goToProcess populates through a callback chosenProcessData:

```
self.goToProcess = function (userProcess) {
    self.chosenProcessId(userProcess);
    self.chosenProcessData = ko.observableArray([]);

    if (userProcess.getPath) {
        if (userProcess.callback && typeof (userProcess.callback) === "function") {
            var arrayResult = userProcess.callback(this.createCallback, this.updateCallback, this.deleteCallback);

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayResult.length; i++) {
                self.chosenProcessData.push(arrayResult[i]);
            }

            alert(self.chosenProcessData().length);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure why making the properties into observables made this stop working. Help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are unbinding chosenProcessData (its connection to the dom) inside of goToProcess with this line

```
self.chosenProcessData = ko.observableArray([]);
```

it should be.

```
self.chosenProcessData();
```

even better remove this line and the for loop and just use

```
self.chosenProccessData(userProcess.callback(this.createCallback, this.updateCallback, this.deleteCallback));
```

Fixed example.

http://jsfiddle.net/5KZun/